# Компиляция C++ в .wasm файл

Tags: c++, emscripten, webassembly

У меня есть следующий C++ код:

```
#include <emscripten.h>
#include <emscripten/val.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace emscripten;

extern "C" {
    EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
    extern void loop() {
        val console = val::global("console");
        console.call<void>("log", std::string("Test"));
    }
}
```

И у меня есть код JS:

```
//"bytecode" содержит .wasm файл
const wasmModule = new WebAssembly.Module(bytecode);

const imports = {};
imports.env = {
    __memory_base : 0,
    __table_base : 0,
    memory: new WebAssembly.Memory({ initial: 256 }),
    table: new WebAssembly.Table({ initial: 0, element: 'anyfunc' })    
};

const wasmInstance = new WebAssembly.Instance(wasmModule, imports);

console.log(wasmInstance.exports);
```

Как скомпилировать код C++ с помощью Emscripten, чтобы функцию `loop` было видно из JavaScript?

Я пробовал кучу разных вариаций из разных примеров, но у меня ничего не получилось.
(`new WebAssembly.Instance` возвращает ошибку
`import object field '__ZdlPv' is not a Function`)

**EDIT:** На данный момент, я использую команду `em++ -s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1 -std=c++17 -O3 src/Main.cpp -o dest/Main.wasm`.
Насколько я понял, в `importObject`'е нужно указывать ряд функций (включая `__ZdlPv`), но откуда их взять?

Comment: А что такое ```extern "C" ... extern void ...``` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для компиляции кода выполните следующую команду:

```
emcc src/module.cc -o example.html -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS='["_loop"]' -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='["ccall", "cwrap"]'
```

Подключите получившийся .js файл и далее вызывайте функцию через `ccall`, либо сделайте обертку с помощью `cwrap`. Я использовал `ccall` в консоли браузера:

```
Module.ccal('_loop')
```

> Я пробовал кучу разных вариаций из разных примеров, но у меня ничего не получилось. (new WebAssembly.Instance возвращает ошибку import object field '__ZdlPv' is not a Function)

Похоже, что имена функций у Вас все-таки мангляться. Не вижу необходимости в использовании ключевого слова `extern` в данном месте (поправьте меня, если это не так):

```
extern void loop() {
    val console = val::global("console");
    console.call<void>("log", std::string("Test"));
}
```

Comment: Использовал команду: `em++ src/Main.cpp -o dest/example.html -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_loop']" -std=c++17 -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS="['ccall','cwrap']"`

Comment: Ошибка: `shared:ERROR: 'error: undefined symbol: _emval_call_void_method`

Comment: @user263096, Вы лишний extern убрали?

Comment: Да, убрал extern перед void.

Comment: @user263096, видимо, дело не в том, как Вы собираете, а _что_ Вы собираете - я говорю об используемых компонентах Emscripten. Вероятно, багается `console.call<void>("log", std::string("Test"))` - попробуйте вместо `std::string("...")` использовать `emscripten::val("...")`;

Comment: Я заменил полностью тело функции на `return`, и ошибка исчезла. Но, похоже, что `val::global` и `console.call<void>` являются также источником проблемы, так как пример не компилируется даже при замене `std::string("...")` на `emscripten::val("...")`.

Comment: Я добавил параметр "--bind" и всё заработало. Спасибо.

Comment: Я снова в тупике. Проблема в том, что WebAssembly выполняется не в браузере и Module работает некорректно.

Comment: @user263096,  node.js? А что Вы понимаете под "некорректно"?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92678/discussion-between-isnullxbh-and-user263096).

Comment: На самом деле, всё достаточно глупо. Я просто хочу поиграть в Screeps (ММО для программистов), используя при этом C++. Но у меня не задалось...

С первоначальной проблемой я разобрался, но мне кажется, что `Module` не подходит. Дело в том, что среда **очень** часто обнуляется и её нужно устанавливать заново. Т. е. инициализировать `Module` приходится слишком часто, а время дорого.

Comment: Я разобрался. Спасибо Вам огромное.

**P.S.:** Мне очень помог следующий репозиторий: https://github.com/ags131/screeps-cpp

Comment: @user263096, рад, если действительно оказался Вам полезным! Спасибо за ссылку, может быть и пригодится!